# Arduino, python, pyserial and socket

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to write a simple webserver on an Arduino to test a few things, but I couldn't find my Arduino with Ethernet on it.

"No worries" I thought, "I'll just write a socket server in python that acts as a proxy for the serial connection".

```
import socket
import serial
host = ''
port = 8001
buffSize= 1024
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((host, port))
serverSocket.listen(1)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=None, dsrdtr =False,rtscts =False,xonxoff =False)
print "Listening..."
send = ""
while 1:
    conn, remoteAddr = serverSocket.accept()
    print "Connection...."
    data = conn.recv(buffSize)
    print "Recieved"
    ser.write("%s\n"%data)
    print "Sent"
    print "Attempting to get reply"
    while ser.inWaiting()>0:
            conn.send( ser.read())
    conn.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

However, whatever I try, it seems that the connection made by the browser resets randomly and I'd get multiple rows of data. And the script resets the Arduino each time it connects or disconnects from the serial port. I tried using RealTerm and I got a proper answer, but python and serialness is just a mess.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The best design would be to put the whole thing into a single event loop, or reactor.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [tcp_serial_redirect.py](http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/pyserial/trunk/pyserial/examples/tcp_serial_redirect.py) script in the PySerial documentation. Is all you need.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I am looking into the serial redirect at this moment.  I'm still a noob, will probably update this comment later.